# How can I call built-in functions in Python using Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, boost

I know we can [import modules](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/embedding/boost_python_import_hpp.html) and just embed Python code in C++ and [evaluate it](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/embedding.html#embedding.boost_python_exec_hpp.function_eval). But how can I use built-in functions like `print` or `open`? These functions off course aren't module. Evaluating embedded `open` statement just gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
```

Stuck. Please help me.

Comment: you can `import builtins`, no idea if this help though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the `builtins` and `io` module and if you want any other function just call the `__module__` attribute to find about which module to import

```
>>> print.__module__
'builtins'
>>> open.__module__
'io'
```

Comment: Are you sure? how will `open.__module__` work if it is showing a `NameError`.

Comment: @scipsycho i dont get it where it is showing a name error? and i used python3 for this

Comment: You are correct @AlbinPaul but all I was saying is that the guy who asked this question is having a `NameError`, so how will he be able to run `open.__module__`

Comment: @scipsycho ok the function open is defined in the module `io` in python3 and `builtin` in python2 which are imported by default in a program so to avoide the name error in c++ the OP must import the builtin module or io module to get it running

Comment: Thanks @AlbinPaul! In my environment, `open` seems to live in `__builtin__`, though. Anyway, by importing `__builtin__` module, my problem has been resolved.